# Frequency distribution table in Tableau

Tags: excel-formula, tableau-api

I'm a new Tableau user and am looking for help/guidance in creating a frequency distribution table from data in an Excel spreadsheet. The data is from a survey, Column A is the respondent's e-mail address.  Column B is the location (State).  Columns C - N are questions from the survey, and answers are listed in the columns on a scale from 1 - 3. The column names look like this:

E-Mail  ..............   State  .........   Question 1  .....   Question 2 .....    Question 3

john.doe ............ MN ................  1  ........................2....................1

mary.smith...........WI...................2.........................3....................2

j.doe....................MN..................3.........................1....................2

I'd like to use Tableau to create a frequency distribution table that would look similar to the following:

```
                  State 1        State 2          State 3
                 1   2   3      1   2   3        1   2   3
```

Question 1

Question 2

Question 3, etc.

I have a feeling that my data is not formatted correctly; however, I'm struggling with how do so.  My questions are: (1) Can I create the frequency distribution table in Tableau using my data in its current format?  (2) If not, how should I format it in order to create the frequency distribution table?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you post few lines of your sample data ? The above you posted I believe is the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but not exactly the way your data is right now .

**first part of solution :**
Good news is you don't need to touch excel for data manipulation, can be done in tableau itself . Select the `edit datasource` from data source context menu.

Select all the states by pressing the control / command button and then `pivot` . This data state is much more flexible to work upon .

**Second part** : I have uploaded desired output at public Tableau. Check and let us know if that is desired.

[Tableau Public Link](https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/frequency_chart/Sheet2#!/publish-confirm)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  This is getting closer; however, I'd like the result to be in a table format, with percentages for distributions.  I'm assuming that if I change the type to a table and add a percentage calculation, that this might work based on the information you've provided.

Comment: Yes, it has Just started . you can go on !